# Getting records for Many 2 Many relation based on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MYSQL database where I have below 3 tables, in which table1 and table2 has many to many relation and the mappings are stored in table3.

Table1:

```
id  key             value
1   Application     java
2   Application     erp
3   Application     sap
4   DB              mysql
5   DB              oracle
6   DB              sql
7   DB              postgres
```

Table2:

```
id  data            type
1   HTML            UI
2   JAVA            Backend
3   JavaScript      UI
4   CSS             UI
5   Query           DB
6   Procedure       DB
7   Function        DB
```

Table3 (Mapping):

```
id  Table1_id   Table2_id
1   1           2
2   1           1
3   1           3
4   1           6
5   2           1
6   2           2
7   3           6
8   4           5
9   4           7
10  5           5
11  5           6
12  5           7
13  6           5
14  6           6
15  7           7
```

Q: I want the result based on key  and value which should return the common data from table2.

For example: If the user pass (key = application and value = java) and (key = db and value = sql)

Then it should return the below result.

```
Key             Value   Data        Type
Application     java    Procedure   db
query           db      Procedure   db
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?`

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I am using MySQL

Answer (score -1):

use join

```
select key,value,data,type from table_mapping m join
table1 t1 on m.Table1_id=t1.id
join table2 t2 on m.Table2_id=t2.id  

 where 
   (key,value) in ( ('application','java'),
                    ('query','db')
                   )
```

Comment: @ShalabhRajput have you checked it?

Comment: Sorry I was using wrong query. It is working but I am not getting desired result. It is returning all the records which have these two key value pairs.

Comment: @ShalabhRajput create dbtable and data https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0

Comment: I have created the table and data in the above link.

Comment: @ShalabhRajput where is the link

Comment: @ShalabhRajput https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0242c5fc2ecc5d05e30093cf045c9b9c